# How can handle form-based authentication together with (jwt)token based authentication in one app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring-boot app. now i have a need to export some data to third parties and i was think of using jwt. now my challenge is how do i use spring-security to handle both form based authentication & jwt base authentication in one app.

In short request that comes to `api/public` has to be authenticated/authorised by using jwt. while all other requests redirect to `/login` page.

Is this possible?

This is how my security configuration looks like right now:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/users").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                .and()
                .rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(3600*24).key("key").userDetailsService(userPrincipalDetailService);
    }
```

Comment: did you implement this ? got any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.antMatcher` on `http` in `configure` method and give the prefix you want spring-security to handle. 
So spring security will only handle the given prefix like so:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/spring_handle_urls/**").authorizeRequests()
            .and() ...
            ;
        }
```

Handle other urls yourself with filters and `jwt`.

Answer (score 1):

Update the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java file using this code.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.addFilterBefore(requestValidateFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spring_handle_urls/**").authenticated();
    http.addFilterAfter(responseValidateFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```